# Command line in mac terminal does not look right

Tags: macos, terminal

Opened my terminal today and each command line starts with a right arrow. Any idea why this happened and how to revert it back to it's original format?

[image]

Comment: Have you changed your PS1 in your .profile recently?  Paste the contents of your .profile, specifically the PS1 line

Comment: Maybe Superuser is a better place for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have changed your prompt. Check a file called `.profile` in your login directory and see if there is line like this:

```
export PS1="\h:\w: "
```

The above is how mine is set. There are lots of possibilities, see [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-linux-unix-bash-shell-setup-prompt.html)